# Programmatically manage IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, wmi

I am currently moving into the web-hosting league. I have to far been adding sites manually in the IIS Manager. But I wonder if there exists an interface, framework or something similair to manage the IIS over the internet - eg. an ASP.NET web-application?

I've read something with WMI, but I am unsure if this is the right path to go? I need to add, edit and delete sites in the IIS Manager on a Windows 2008 server running IIS 7.0 programmatically.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS 7 has a programmable management interface, that  is accessible from managed code - go to http://www.iis.net/ and read up on it. No need to use anything else.

Comment: Is it possible you can link me direct? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: Sure. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/36/managing-and-maintaining-iis-70/. There is a whole sectiion about automating.

Comment: I can't find automating IIS on the link. Can you share correct link?